# iOS - SFSafariViewController Freezes/Hanging

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I wrote the simplest possible code to launch a SFSafariViewController in my view controllers 'viewDidAppear' method.

```
  let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!)
  self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It works fine on the iOS simulator, but in my iPhone it shows the SFSafarViewController, but doesn't load the page. I have an iPhone 6 (iOS 9.1):

[image]